# Can an open source project be considered a cooperative game?

Tags: game-theory

Quote from https://opensource.google.com/docs/why/#engineering-economics:

> While open source work may have benevolent results, it is not an act of
>   charity. Releasing work as open source and the corresponding
>   contribution process eventually result in a higher return on the
>   initial investment made versus the alternative closed source process.
>   John Nash, a famous mathematician and subject of the Oscar winning
>   movie “A Beautiful Mind”, won the Nobel prize in economics for his
>   work on “cooperative games”. He demonstrated that cooperating is not a
>   zero sum game and that by working together all participants may yield
>   higher returns than the investment they make. The best real world
>   example of this may be open source software.
>
> Stephen Walli in his blog post on open source motivations writes,
>   “This wasn’t contributing back out of altruism. It was engineering
>   economics. It was the right thing to do, and contributed back to the
>   hardening of the compiler suite we were using ourselves. It was what
>   makes well run open source projects work.”
>
> One good example of this is Angular, a web application framework that
>   is used extensively inside of Google. Angular saw rapid adoption by
>   web developers who built extensions and tools which in turn increases
>   the value inside Google as Google uses these extension and tools
>   internally.

Which leads me to the question, is the above quote true from a mathematical point of view? Is it an open source software truly a [cooperative game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_game_theory)?

Answer (score 1):

My short answer is no, as the standard definition of cooperative game is one where binding contracts can be written (see the wikipedia post you cited in your question).  Just because a game is called non-cooperative does not mean there is no cooperation. But if I understand open-source software (and I'm no expert) the developers find it in their interest to contribute, but they don't have a contract enforcing their work.  I would say this is an example of a non-cooperative game that is not zero sum (zero sum means my gain is your loss) where both (all) parties can gain.

More broadly the question is ambiguous, as it is a question of what is the best way to model a particular feature we seen in the real world.  Thus, for all I said about cooperative versus non-cooperative games, a classic way to model perfect competition is often as a cooperative game, using the concept of the Core.